# Creating customised bar chart in Dundas Dashboards

Tags: dundas

I want to customise the bar chart with custom images.
Instead of simple bars, I would like to use images of buildings to represent property data. Is it possible in Dundas Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by changing the fill for the series or the points to use an image brush.

If you want all bars to have the same fill, set it using the Chart -> Series -> Fill property from the property grid.

If you want each bar to have a different image, you'll need to set it via script.

For example:

```
var imageBrush = new DashboardImageBrush();
imageBrush.Url = new DashboardImageUrl("http://www.example.com/MyFill.png");

BarChart1.Series[0].Points[0].Fill = imageBrush;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by changing the fill for the series or the points to use an image brush.

```
var imageBrush = new DashboardImageBrush();
imageBrush.Url = new DashboardImageUrl("http://www.example.com/MyFill.png");

BarChart1.Series[0].Points[0].Fill = imageBrush;
```